# Unity3d Cannot open project | Fatal Error - The Project is on case sensitive file system

Tags: unity-game-engine, filesystems

I startet a unity-project, I installed the github plugin - https://unity.github.com/ 
I had a weird bug and I needed to delete my local project and I reinstalled Unity.
I have Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 and I used it to `git clone url` my repo/project 
Now when I try to open the project with unity I get the following Error:
`FATAL ERROR! The Project is on case sensitive file system.`
[image: Fatal Error!]

But when I create a new project in the same directory `R:/Unity_Projects/`it works. 
How can i resolve this Issue? Is it because of the Linux Subsystem that the folder i cloned from git is case-sensitive? If so how can I undo this? I tried `fsutil file setcasesensitiveinfo Unity_Projects/ disable` but it doesn't change the behaviour.
I also tried to use a different hard drive but I get the same fatal error

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same issue tonight and tried using MinGW to run `git clone` instead of the Linux Subsystem, and it worked fine.

Hope you've solved your issue!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, fsutil.exe doesn't have an option to apply this setting recursively to the project folders.  Run PowerShell as an Administrator, cd into Unity_Projects and then this command will disable the case sensitivity for all subfolders:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory).FullName | ForEach-Object {fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo $_ disable}
```

If you have any files in the directory that have the same name, but different case (e.g. casesensitivetest vs CaseSensitiveTest), then the command to disable will fail with an error:

```
Error: The directory is not empty.
```

Comment: If anyone is getting this error from creating a new project from the Unity Hub, this answer worked for me. I just created a new folder and ran this command in the directory that contained this new one. Afterwards, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new folder in the windows explorer, and copy and paste all the files in the broken folder

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [wscourge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960274/6102241)'s answer, instead of cloning the repository using the *Linux subsystem for Windows* I removed it and cloned it using *git for windows*, this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when using Github for Desktop on Windows. To get it working I had to do both clown and download:

1. "Download as Zip" from GitHub.com, named "ProjectA"
2. Clone with GitHub for Desktop, named "ProjectB"
3. Copy the hidden .git folder from "ProjectB" to "ProjectA"
4. Delete "ProjectB" and rename and add "ProjectA" into GitHub Desktop and Unity Hub.

When downloading as a Zip Unity worked fine, but there is no git repo setup localy, so copying that from the cloned one did the trick.